# variables in php within html

Tags: php, html

I am working on creating an admin website using [AdminLTE](https://almsaeedstudio.com/themes/AdminLTE/index2.html) free template in the prosses I'm having a problem with getting a variable from within PHP brackets to print in the HTML page
I want to do something like this:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
   <head >
<!-- rest of the page -->
    <span class="info-box-text" name= "msg" > 
   <!-- I want to print x here inside the info box -->
    <script> <?php echo $x ?> </script>

   </span>
    <!-- the function that has the output comes after it is called -->
    <script>
    <?php
        do somthing to $x
        $output_messege = "the result of something=".$x"."    
    ?>
    </script>
    
 
   </head >
</html>
```

Comment: What is the result you are getting? Is PHP installed?

Comment: Are you getting any errors ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason your code doesn't work is because you have wrapped the echo in the script tag. Remember that php is executed on server and it sends out a plain HTML. So by the time your code comes to the browser, the echoed variable is in a script tag which is not show on the page !

So you can use 'echo' command to print simple text or 'printf' to output a formatted string (useful to print arrays etc)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
    <?php
          // let's do the 'somthing to $x' so that later refrence has the updated $x value
          $output_messege = "the result of something=".$x"."    
      ?>
  </span>
</head>
<body>
<span class="info-box-text" name="msg"> 
    <!-- we can print the output_message here with a simple echo. notice that there no script tags ! -->
    <?php echo $output_messege ?> </span>
</body>
</html>
```

Edit : 
To elaborate, I feel you've misunderstood the way PHP and JS works. PHP works on the server. When the page is being rendered by the server by 'PHP renderer' it finds everything between the `<?php ?>` markup and executes them. So if you put in a echo there, it will do just as expected, echo the variable or the string at that point. 
After all this a plain valid HTML page is generated with no PHP logic or code and this is what the browser receives. Now JS comes into play.
Browser will now find everything under the `<script> </script>` tag and execute it.